# Mysql Error - Blank white screen

Tags: mysql, server

My website went 'down' this morning, by that I mean we didn't receive any alert that told us it went down (we use pingdom) but the site was not accessible. I checked the logs and could see the following errors; I'm struggling to interpret these logs.

Can anyone help?

> $
>   May 19 06:29:01 ip-10-91-158-95 kernel: [82861.450898] init: mysql post-start process (6881) terminated with status 1
>   May 19 06:29:01 ip-10-91-158-95 kernel: [82861.465199] type=1400 audit(1463639341.257:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=6956 comm="apparmor_parser"
>   May 19 06:29:01 ip-10-91-158-95 kernel: [82861.647740] init: mysql main process (6968) terminated with status 1
>   May 19 06:29:01 ip-10-91-158-95 kernel: [82861.647779] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Or restarting the whole mysql service?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an error caused by an update.  There is a solution for this problem explained here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/127264/cant-start-mysql-mysql-respawning-too-fast-stopped

You have to edit your /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and change

```
default-character-set = utf8
default-collation     = utf8_general_ci
```

to

```
character_set_server  = utf8
collation_server      = utf8_general_ci
```

or you can simply run this command in terminal

```
dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

Check the launchpad bug report here: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/958120